# iOS PWA - Open Maps returns to blank screen

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-maps, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA that I have saved to the home screen of my iPhone. The PWA has a Google Maps link that opens correctly in both fullscreen and browser modes, however when opening from full screen mode on iOS, the link opens, then switches to the Google Maps App (if installed).

When I close the maps app and return to the PWA it shows a blank screen and does not return to the previous view that contained the link.

```
function openMap(lat, lng) {
    var win = window.open("https://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng + "", '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the PWA from opening the map link in the popover Safari viewer and just launching the link in the full Safari app or any other way to fix/prevent this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code below fixes the issue of opening the map in a new tab when in the browser but not when running as a PWA on iOS.

```
function openMap(lat, lng) {
        if (('standalone' in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone) {
            var win = window.open("https://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng + "", '_top');
            win.focus();
        } else {
            var win = window.open("https://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng + "", '_blank');
            win.focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm Tom Coomer's code works within a PWA running on iOS 12.3.1 - i.e., the user's native maps app will open correctly. Upon closing the native maps app and returning to the PWA will show the correct view and not a white screen.

I wanted to keep the maps call local to user's native maps app, so I added a platform check:

```
const mapsSelector = (lat, lng) => {
  if (['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod'].includes(navigator.platform)) {
    const win = window.open(`maps://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=${lat},${lng}&amp;ll=`, '_top');
    return win.focus();
  }
  /* default to Google */
  const win = window.open(`https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=${lat},${lng}&amp;ll=`, '_top');
  return win.focus();
};
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! I was going crazy trying to understand what the issue was